# Best practice for user-sorted has_many associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several models where my users need to be able to sort some has_many associations. That is, they need to be able to add, remove and prioritise certain relationships.

So far, my idea is to have an `order` property on the associated models, and handle updating them from the frontend.

However, I feel like this is prone to many errors. On the other hand, I also feel like introducing an intermediary table/model would probably be an overkill.

Is there a best practice to handle this (not so uncommon) situation?

Comment: Best practices just cover basic tenets- stuff that actually can be described in a single sentance. Looking for them for overly specific or complex cases is not very constructive.  How to actually structure an application with complex buisness logic which can be built in many different ways depending on your requirements and scale is not an on topic question as its very broad in scale and primarily opinion based. You might want to try a discussion forum instead.

Comment: @max I don't believe a sortable list is "complex business logic"

Comment: Then why havent you written it already?

Comment: @max Because Rails has lots of conventions for trivial stuff like this and I'm not sure if this is something where I ought to reinvent the wheel.

This is actually stuff that can be described in one sentence: "I need a has_many relationship where the associated records are arbitrarily ordered"

I do have a solution for it, but I believe this is something so simple that it might actually have a convention / best practice covering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that adding the `order` column is the standard way. There is a fairly popular gem called `acts_as_list` that does it that way. I've used that gem and didn't have any issues, but it was in an admin app (very low chance of concurrency issues).

Comment: I ended up exploring these two options, had the impression that `acts_as_list` might be a tad bit more complicated to wire up with my frontend than what I'm looking for here and ended up manually handling it with an `order` column.